# SLD styling in QGIS, elsefilter not working

Tags: qgis, sld

I need to figure out how to make elsefilter work when imported into QGIS (2.8.3) via sld.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
<NamedLayer>
<se:Name>dopravni_znacky</se:Name>
<UserStyle>
  <se:Name>dopravni_znacky</se:Name>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <se:ElseFilter/>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#991321</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>2</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>umisteni</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>v chodníku</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:ExternalGraphic>
            <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="transport/transport_aerodrome.svg"/>
            <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
          </se:ExternalGraphic>
          <se:Size>10</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

When I use this sld, these styles overwrite each other (I see two overlapping icons), I want the first style to be shown only when the conditions are not met.

Comment: Should not be <se:ElseFilter/> but <sld:ElseFilter/>? does not work either way.

Answer (score 5):

As you can read [here](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/ElseFilter) about the `ElseFilter`,

> A Rule containing an `ElseFilter`  is evaluated if and only if no other Rule in the current Style matches.
>   All Rules in a Style are evaluated sequentially from top to bottom, testing each Rule's Filter against the current Object.

This means that you have to list all your rules, and your last rule should contain the `ElseFilter` (I have changed the rules' order in your code). However, if you only do that, QGIS will ignore the first rule, because `PropertyIsEqualTo` applies to all your objects, so it styles them twice. So you have to add a new filter to the last rule, `PropertyIsNotEqualTo`, to eliminate your problem.

Here is your modified (working) code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
<NamedLayer>
<se:Name>dopravni_znacky</se:Name>
<UserStyle>
  <se:Name>dopravni_znacky</se:Name>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>umisteni</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>v chodníku</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:ExternalGraphic>
            <se:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="transport/transport_aerodrome.svg"/>
            <se:Format>image/svg+xml</se:Format>
          </se:ExternalGraphic>
          <se:Size>10</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <se:ElseFilter/>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>umisteni</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>v chodníku</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#991321</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>2</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>  
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

It is stated [here](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2015-June/038239.html) that QGIS ELSE expression is a bug, as you said earlier.

If you select 'Categorized' to style your features (considering that you have uncategorized/else features), 
QGIS listens and shows them accordingly. But if you go to Rule-based, even tough QGIS styles the ELSE category 
differently, these features are styled twice.

[image: ELSE category]

After I exported the sld that QGIS created, I saw this:

```
<!--Parser Error: syntax error, unexpected ELSE - Expression was: ELSE-->
```

So QGis cannot render the ELSE filter.

As a workaround (I don't know if you can use this, you said that you have a lot of conditions) you can try this:

First, list all your conditions, based on `PropertyIsEqualTo` (without using the `ElseFilter`):

```
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>condition1</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#de0000</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.00</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>condition2</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#fdeb7f</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.00</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    ...condition3, condition4
```

And then your last rule should contain `PropertyIsNotEqualTo` all your conditions listed above:

```
<se:Rule>
      <se:Name></se:Name>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
          <ogc:And>
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>condition1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>condition2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
            <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>condition3</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
              </ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>condition4</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsNotEqualTo>
        </ogc:And>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#9dda58</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Fill>
        <se:Stroke>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.00</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.26</se:SvgParameter>
          <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
```

The result of this will be (I used my own features to test it):

[image]

Comment: This works. What if I want to style my layer based on different properties, and different values. How do I define which objects are not yet styled - and I have a lot of those conditions?

Comment: For Example this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a9e2d34da165cc52e7ce

How do I use your approach here?

Comment: Another thing: I do not think that 
  `<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
    <ogc:PropertyName>umisteni</ogc:PropertyName>
    <ogc:Literal>v chodníku</ogc:Literal>
 </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>`
styles all of my data. This basically only styles data that have value "v chodníku" in the attribute "umístění" - definitely not all of my data.

Comment: I have edited my answer in order to give a solution, please see above. I have tried your GitHub example, and QGis styles all the features twice. The first rule doesn't have a filter and is applied to all the features, and then the other rules (with a filter) are applied again to each feature.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking your time and trying to solve this problem. Your workaround is fine, however I have to style data with way more conditions I am showing here - and based on more attributes.

This definitely is QGIS bug, as geoserver proccesses my sld the way I have meant it to be.

ElseFilter should not need any conditions in it specified, it should function as "go through all the rules, if the object you are proccessing right now meets the condition, use the style, if not, continue - and then the <ElseFilter/> basically just styles any object that has not met any condition

Comment: No problem, happy to help :). Maybe this post will also help others struggling with the issue.

Comment: Let's hope it gets fixed. Sld should be the standard - when QGIS cannot handle it it's bad.

Answer (score 3):

So, after extensive testing, I have come to a conclusion that this is indeed QGIS bug. I have tested my sld file in QGIS 2.12.3 and in GeoServer. These are my results:

QGIS:
[image]

using the same sld file in GeoServer:
[image]

Below is my sld file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
<NamedLayer>
<se:Name>dopravni_znacky</se:Name>
<UserStyle>
  <se:Name>dopravni_znacky</se:Name>
  <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>platne_kriterium</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>platne_kriterium</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:PropertyName>ukotveni</ogc:PropertyName>
          <ogc:Literal>sloup VO</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.00</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>5</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
    <se:Rule>
      <se:Name>default</se:Name>
      <se:Description>
        <se:Title>default</se:Title>
      </se:Description>
      <se:ElseFilter/>
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#18d300</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">0.00</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>2</se:Size>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>
    </se:Rule>
  </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Basically my sld file says that my points should be red circles when they match my first rule, otherwise they should be green dots. GeoServer does what I've specified in my sld file exactly as how I would expected, however QGIS seems to ignore the se:ElseFilter and just renders every feature with second rule regardless (which here you can see as those green dots in the middle of red circles - both rules rendered at the same time)

I will open a ticket and hope that this gets fixed.